# DialogFragment over Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I want to display a DialogFragment over the soft keyboard. (I have some emojicons in my dialog and I want to switch between soft keyboard and emojicons like whatsapp does)

I have set the softInputMode to LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE but I am not able to position my dialogFragment over the keyboard. I tried to set the window gravity to bottom but it does not work

This is how it looks like
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a PopupWindow and without fragments.
I have also made a [repo](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) on github incase anyone is stuck on the same issue.